# Rxjs link is not working?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs5

**In system.config.js file, i used this rxjs link:**

> 'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10/'

**it makes error bcz,it generate another one slash and add it to the end of link, bcz of this my source is not defind **

**instead of above link, if i use this link, it will work. i want to know the reason?**

> 'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10'
>
> my system.config.js file

```js
System.config({
    transpiler: "typescript",
    typescriptOptions: {
        compilerOptions: {
            target: "umd",
            module: "commonjs",
            moduleResolution: "node",
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
            experimentalDecorators: true
        }
    },
    paths: {
        "syncfusion:": "{{:CDN_LINK}}",
        "angular:": "https://unpkg.com/@angular/"
    },
    map: {
        app: 'app',
        typescript: "https://unpkg.com/typescript@2.2.2/lib/typescript.js",
          "@syncfusion/ej2-base": "syncfusion:ej2-base/dist/ej2-base.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-dropdowns": "syncfusion:ej2-dropdowns/dist/ej2-dropdowns.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-inputs": "syncfusion:ej2-inputs/dist/ej2-inputs.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-lists": "syncfusion:ej2-lists/dist/ej2-lists.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-data": "syncfusion:ej2-data/dist/ej2-data.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-popups": "syncfusion:ej2-popups/dist/ej2-popups.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-buttons": "syncfusion:ej2-buttons/dist/ej2-buttons.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-ng-base": "syncfusion:ej2-ng-base/dist/ej2-ng-base.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-ng-popups": "syncfusion:ej2-ng-popups/dist/ej2-ng-popups.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-ng-buttons": "syncfusion:ej2-ng-buttons/dist/ej2-ng-buttons.umd.min.js",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-ng-dropdowns": "syncfusion:ej2-ng-dropdowns/dist/ej2-ng-dropdowns.umd.min.js",
 

        '@angular/core': 'angular:core@5.2.10/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'angular:common@5.2.10/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'angular:compiler@5.2.10/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'angular:http@5.2.10/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'angular:forms@5.2.10/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'angular:router@5.2.10/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'angular:platform-browser@5.2.10/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'angular:platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.10/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/material': 'angular:material@5.2.10/bundles/material.umd.js',
        'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10'
    },
    packages: {
        'app': { main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'ts' },
        'rxjs': { main: 'index' },
    }
});
 
System.import('app');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because using :

> 'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10/'

you will get all the the rxjs JavaScript files not the script.

if you want to use rxjs library you should use :

> 'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: Copy-paste the urls both with and without slash into your browser.

The one with the slash will point to the folder with all JS files, while the one without slash will actually transfer you to the file:

> https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10/Rx.js

Which is your actual config file

Comment: i added my file above please check it

Comment: thats not the issue......if i give slash(in end of link), when it generate full link path .....the llink became like this..............."https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.10//unpredit.ts"

Comment: I see. Strange behaviour, this will still not answer the "Why?", but also in the github repo it is without slash, see [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/examples/_common/system-config.ts)